# Toggle logscale option for dygraph in rmarkdown

Tags: javascript, r, markdown, knitr, dygraphs

I would really like a dygraph that comes with a checkbox to toggle the Y axis to logscale. I know I can do this with shiny, but I can do pretty much everything else I need for this project using rmarkdown without shiny, which allows me to deliver .html without having to set up a shiny server.

I know it isn't complicated on the dygraph side of things
http://dygraphs.com/options.html#logscale

And I think rmarkdown is certainly flexible enough to do it
http://livefreeordichotomize.com/2017/01/24/custom-javascript-visualizations-in-rmarkdown/

But how?

Comment: I still have to set up a shiny server to do that, right?

Comment: "These documents combine the expressiveness of R Markdown with the interactivity of Shiny. These documents can be run locally on the desktop or be deployed to ShinyApps or Shiny Server v1.2 (see the Deployment section below for more details)." http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_shiny.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `{.tabset}` and plot both scales separately.

````
---
output:
  html_document:
    code_folding: hide
    theme: flatly
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 3
    toc_float: yes
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(dygraphs)
```


# Plots {.tabset .tabset-fade .tabset-pills}


## Normal Y

```{r plot_norm}
dygraph(AirPassengers, main = "Airline Passengers / Month") %>%
  dyAxis("x", drawGrid = FALSE) %>%
  dyAxis("y", label = "Passengers (Thousands)") %>%
  dyOptions(includeZero = TRUE, 
            axisLineColor = "navy", 
            gridLineColor = "lightblue")
```


## Log Y

```{r plot_log}
dygraph(AirPassengers, main = "Airline Passengers / Month") %>%
  dyAxis("x", drawGrid = FALSE) %>%
  dyAxis("y", label = "Passengers (Thousands)", logscale = TRUE) %>%
  dyOptions(logscale = TRUE,
            axisLineColor = "navy", 
            gridLineColor = "lightblue")
```
````